# Word Press custom form links

Tags: ajax, wordpress

On my Word Press website, I have a section on my website where I am displaying the job categories.

[image]

My only issue is that I can't seem to create custom links for any of the categories on my site. Like 'http://example.com/find-a-job/?s=search_categories%football'

I was curious if anyone had an idea on how to create custom links for Wordpress forms that auto-fill one of the fields to what I want it to be.

If it means anything, I believe the form is AJAX.

Thanks.

Comment: For customizing category permalink URL please open permalink menu from admin. Please have a look as below:

http://example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

Or you can update this with creating custom category-template in wp theme

Comment: @GovindSoni thank you very much, lead me in the right direction and now it is fixed.